# How to hide the header from Tab navigation in react navigation?

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

I have created a react native application. There I am using react native stack navigator with bottom tab navigator. This is how It looks like.

This is how my application looks like.
[image]

What I want to do is remove the circled header bar and green color circled line over the bottom tabs.

This is my app.js file.

```
import React from "react";
import Login from "./src/components/Login/Login";
import Register from "./src/components/Register/Register";
import Route from './src/route'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Route></Route>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my route.js file.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
// import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import IonIcon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import { Image } from "react-native";

import LoginScreen from "./components/Login/Login";
import HomeScreen from "./components/Home/Home";
import FinesScreen from "./components/Fines/Fines";
import LocationScreen from "./components/Location/Location";
import SettingsScreen from "./components/Settings/Settings";

const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,

      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: false,
        tabBarIcon: () => (
          <Image source={require("../assets/invalid-name.png")} />
        )
      }
    },
    fines: {
      screen: FinesScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: false,
        headerMode: "none",
        tabBarIcon: () => (
          <Image source={require("../assets/icon-service-fines.png")} />
        )
      }
    },
    location: {
      screen: LocationScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: false,
        headerMode: "none",
        tabBarIcon: () => <Image source={require("../assets/shape.png")} />
      }
    },
    settings: {
      screen: SettingsScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: false,
        headerMode: "none",
        tabBarIcon: () => <Image source={require("../assets/settings.png")} />
      }
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    swipeEnabled: true,
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#FFFFFF",
      inactiveTintColor: "#F8F8F8",
      style: {
        backgroundColor: "#fffff"
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: "#87B56A",
        borderBottomWidth: 2
      }
    }
  }
);

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    tab: { screen: TabNav }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "login"
  },
  (navigationOptions = {
    headerMode: "none"
  })
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default AppContainer;
```

This is my home screen code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {
  StyleSheet,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  Image,
  ScrollView
} from "react-native";


class Home extends Component{
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Home</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

All other three-tab component code also similar to home.

I looked for a solution to this problem mush but I was unable to do so. So can someone help me to solve this issue? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your are using Stack navigator,in a createStackNavigator set headerMode to none i,e
`const Navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Resume: Resume,
    Promotion: Promotion,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Resume',
    headerMode: 'none',
  },
);`
or in a class like your are using make it return function

Answer (score 2):

At first, You create a instance of Tab Navigator like this:

```html
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
```

Now you can create a function, and within that function you can set tab navigator.

```html
<Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        header: () => null,
      }}
>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="dashboard"
        component={Dashboard}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Dashboard',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <Icon
              name="view-dashboard-outline"
              color={color}
              size={ICONSIZES.h1}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="StockItemsStackScreen"
        component={StockItemsStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Stock Items',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialIcon name="list-alt" color={color} size={ICONSIZES.h1} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="StockInStackScreen"
        component={StockInStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Stock-in',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <Icon name="cart-arrow-down" color={color} size={ICONSIZES.h1} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="ConsumptionStackScreen"
        component={ConsumptionStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Consumption',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <Icon name="cart-arrow-up" color={color} size={ICONSIZES.h1} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```